# Using a Proxy for domain interface types with RequestFactory

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, requestfactory

I have the following Entity:

```
public class Action{
    ....
    Ref<Followable> target;
    ....
    public Followable getTarget() {
        return target.get();
    }
}
```

Where `Followable`is an interface that several other Entities in my domain implement. I use the `Followable`type so that Action can reference several types of entities.

I want know to make a Proxy type for `Action` but, in order to be able to expose `getTarget()` I need to have a proxy for `Followable`which is an interface.

The trick here is that in the client, I would like to be able to cast `Followable` objects to their actual type...

Can I do something like this with RequestFactory?
Is there a major flaw in using this Followable type? If yes, how could I architect my domain to be able to reference different entity types from Action?

Answer (score 0):

I was given the answer on the [GWT google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/uFB1MMRIXWY) by @ThomasBroyer and @Jens.

Polimorphism is possible since GWT 2.4.0.

See:

[GWT 2.4.0 RequestFactory polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625692/gwt-2-4-0-requestfactory-polymorphism)

https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactory_2_4#Polymorphism_support

Except that it only works for classes, not interfaces, for the domain objects: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5762